# Xcode 6 - Compile source with Objective-C++ without add .mm file

Tags: ios, swift, llvm, objective-c++

I am integrating a SDK which implemented with Objective-C++, so the SDK integration guide says

> "Xcode's Project -> Edit Active Target -> Build -> GCC4.2 - Language -> Compile Sources As 'Objective-C++'".

It seems that this guide is out of date, I am using Xcode 6, I can only find a similar config

> "TAEGETS - Build Settings - Apple LLVM 6.1... - Compile Sources As",

However, changing this config to Objective-C++ can not solve the link problem. I am developing with Swift, add a `.mm` file is ugly to me.

Anyone can help me?

[image]

Comment: Those are linker errors, not compiler errors.  Looks like you are missing the C++ runtime library

Comment: But adding a `.mm` file can solve the problem.

Comment: That probably means Xcode decides "this project contains C++" and therefore links with the C++ runtime library.  However it should also come to this conclusion after setting "Compile source as Objective-C++".

Comment: That is what confused me too.

Comment: By the way, I am using CocoaPods.